# Meteor template not getting it's data for some reason. Confused about when to subscribe

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

My Meteor template isn't getting it's data. It's a routed one, and it just is showing nothing for all of its handlebars fields.

Here's the pertinent parts of my router.

```js
this.route('admin', {
    before: function() { if (!isAdmin()) Router.go('home'); },
    data: function()  { return Meteor.users.find(); }, 
    waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('adminAllUsers'); }
});

this.route('adminUser', {
    path: '/admin/:_id',
    before: function() { if (!isAdmin()) Router.go('home'); },
    // this is a potential problem area.
    data: function() { return Meteor.users.find(this.params._id); },
    waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('adminUser', this.params._id); }
});
```

My publications seem to be doing their job, since when I do things like `Meteor.users.find().fetch()` in the console, the right objects with the right fields all pop up. If you'd like to see the relevant publications just ask.

My templates:

```html
<template name="admin">
    {{#each this}}
        // Here, since I'm using 'pathFor', it passes the id automatically. I'm not sure if that means I don't have to use the 'data' hook in the router.
        <a href="{{pathFor 'adminUser'}}">{{customer.firstname}} {{customer.lastname}}</a>: ${{customer.balance}}
    {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="adminUser">
    Admin user
    {{testing}}
    // None of these show up, not even the id.
    {{_id}}
    {{customer.firstname}}
    {{#each emails}}
        {{address}}
    {{/each}}
    {{#with customer}}
        {{firstname}} {{lastname}}
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

And also I have this helper in my javascript:

```js
Template.adminUser.testing = function() {
    console.log(this);
}
```

When this helper does its log, it prints this:

```
Object {collection: LocalCollection, selector_id: "veW6jvfSM5Jc46Wbj", selector_f: function, sort_f: undefined, skip: undefined…}
```

When I dig into that it has everything there, and that `selector_id` is correct for the route.

Why isn't anything showing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is simple, the data method of a RouteController will be used as the current data context of the rendered template.

Your admin route is OK, because you return a LocalCursor from Collection.find and you iterate over the cursor using {{#each this}}.

However in adminUser, you're also returning a LocalCursor but what you really need is a plain Object representing the user, because the template references its members.

Simply change Collection.find(id) to Collection.findOne(id) and you're good to go !